# ¿Cómo puedo pasar más de un término (o más de una categoría) al loop para poder mostrar la publicación en más de una categoría o término?

Tags: wordpress, bucles

estoy creando una lista de páginas dinámicas que será colocada en un widget para mostrarse en las páginas individuales de mi sitio, mi idea es mostrar una lista de páginas similares a la página mostrada, entendiendo como "similares" aquellas páginas que están en la misma categoría/termino.

Sin embargo estoy trabajando con varias `taxonomías` y `custom post types`, y para hacer que este código funcione en diferentes `custom post types` y `taxonomías personalizadas`, he usado algunos trucos que se me vinieron a la cabeza para hacer que todo coincida, y la verdad es que funciona bien, pero le falta algo.

Acá mi código, su funcion es muy simple, crear a partir del `post_type` el `nombre de la taxonomía`, para luego mostrar en función del término asociado las demás publicaciones asociadas al término.

Por lo tanto, cuando elija alguna categoría para la publicación; en dicha publicación se mostrará un widget con una lista de las demás páginas en ese mismo `término`, sin importar a cual de mis 8 `cpt` haga referencia y sin importar a qué taxonomía y término se refiere, ya que todo se genera a partir del nombre del `post_type` y del string `'category_'.'$post_type'`.

Acá se muestra una parte de la lista de términos:

[image: Algunos terminos]

Y esta es la lista que se genera a partir del código:

[image: la lista que se genera a partir del código]

Acá el código:

```
<?php
$get_post = get_post_type(); // 'item'
$tax_name = 'category_' . $get_post; // 'category_item' (la taxonomia)
$term_list = get_the_term_list($post->ID, $tax_name); // 'Armaduras' (el termino asociado)
$term_sup = $term_list;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => get_post_type(),
    $tax_name   => $term_sup,
    'showposts' => '1500',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
// Start the Loop
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><a class="text-decoration-none text-reset" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('field_6239377639075'); ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Sin embargo, el problema que me trae por acá es que `no puedo agregar más de una categoría` (o término de taxonomía), si lo hago no aparece ninguna página en la lista:

Acá agregué 2 categorias / terminos:

[image: Acá agregué 2 categorias / terminos]

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto la pregunta en cuestión es:

¿Cómo puedo pasar más de un término (o más de una categoría) al loop para poder mostrar la publicación en más de una categoría o término?

De ese modo la página actual podrá ser listada bajo varios términos y no solamente uno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el parámetro `tax_query` en tus `$args` (ver [taxonomy-parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)) que debiera tener el formato

```
  $args = [
    'post_type' => get_post_type(),
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' =>  $tax_name,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => ['Armadura','Alimentos']
        ],
    ],
    'showposts' => '1500',
  ];
```

para obtener ese array de slugs, en vez de

```
  $term_list = get_the_term_list($post->ID, $tax_name);
```

que te entrega un string concatenando con comas, debes usar:

```
  $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($postID, $tax_name, ['fields' => 'slugs']);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, funciona perfecto. Agregaré el código final a la publicación para que le sirva a más personas. Le deseo lo mejor.

Comment: yo creo que poner la solución dentro de la misma pregunta más bien genera confusión, pero es sólo una opinión personal

Answer (score 0):

### Acá la soulicón

Selecciono **más de una** categoría / término:

[image: Más de una categoría]

Y acá viene el código detras de escena:

```
<?php
$get_post   = get_post_type();
$tax_name   = 'category_' . $get_post;

$postID     = get_queried_object_id();
$term_list  = wp_get_post_terms($postID, $tax_name, ['fields' => 'slugs']);

$args       = array(
    'post_type' => get_post_type(),
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => $tax_name,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_list,
        ],
    ],
    'showposts' => '1500',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
// Start the Loop
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><a class="text-decoration-none text-reset" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('nombre'); ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Y este es el resultado final, una lista con las publicaciones asociadas a los términos / categorías de la publicación actual, en este caso es una lista con todas las Armaduras y todos los Alimentos:

[image: todas las publicaciones asociadas a las categorias de la pagina]